# android drawable marker nullExceptionPointer

Tags: java, android, google-maps, drawable

I have my drawable object which works fine first time, but when I try to use it second time(clear map overlays list)  nullExceptionPointer occurs.

my code:

```
Drawable myMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);;
```

then in many place I use (or rather try to use) myMarker.But it crushes.

Comment: Post some more code, and paste the log to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use Drawable from one activity in another activity. It was not working until I made it static.